# Is this R neural network overfitting?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network

I have built an neural network with the neuralnet package in R to predict stock prices. My model and code works well, but I am getting an accuracy around 97-99%, which makes me a bit suspicious:

Is my model overfitting?

[This](https://gofile.io/?c=KUzbLW) is the Dataset I am using (which is already scaled), and [this](https://gofile.io/?c=zenlWe) is my original Dataset (not scaled), which I need to calc the accuracy for. This is the code to build and test the model:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
}

nn_df <- as.data.frame(lapply(nn_df, normalize))    

nn_df_train = as.data.frame(nn_df[1:1965,]) #1965
nn_df_test = as.data.frame(nn_df[1966:2808,]) #843

# NN for Sentiment GI
nn_model <- neuralnet(GSPC.Close ~ GSPC.Open +GSPC.Low + GSPC.High + SentimentGI, data = nn_df_train, hidden=5, linear.output=TRUE, threshold=0.01)

plot(nn_model)

nn_model$result.matrix

nn_pred <- compute(nn_model, nn_df_test)
nn_pred$net.result

results <- data.frame(actual = nn_df_test$GSPC.Close, prediction = nn_pred$net.result)
results

#calc accuracy
predicted = results$prediction * abs(diff(range(nn_org$GSPC.Close))) + min(nn_org$GSPC.Close)
actual = results$actual * abs(diff(range(nn_org$GSPC.Close))) + min(nn_org$GSPC.Close)
comparison = data.frame(predicted,actual)
#deviation=((actual-predicted)/actual)
deviation= abs((actual-predicted)/actual)
comparison=data.frame(predicted,actual,deviation)
accuracy=1-abs(mean(deviation))
accuracy
```

Comment: Did you run on a validation set? You usually split your data into several subsets one of which is used to test how well your model generalizes / how much it overfits.

Comment: No, I just split the data into training (70%) and test (30%). And as you can see from the code I used the test to test my model.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. I changed the title of your question and the wording of its text to make clear what you are asking. You're not asking anything about stock prices; you're asking if your model is overfitting. However, I'm not sure your question is a good fit for Stack Overflow. Please check out https://stats.stackexchange.com/ and consider asking it there. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there's only a risk of overfitting if:

- the model has been trained on several iterations, for which every iteration shuffles the content of the training and test groups
- the model had been optimized after the parameters have
  been tweaked iteratively in order to get good accuracy in your test
  data.

In both situations, a validation set would be necessary.

If none of the above is the case, then that accuracy is clearly more reliable. Even so, you could test the same model with an extra set of data just to confirm your results.

**Edit**: let me add that, although surprisingly, I got a similar accuracy in a  30-day in the future stock prediction model by only using linear regression; so I do not know whether this level of accuracy is good enough in the stock market prediction area.